# Summing a column value of duplicates in another value with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, join, merge

Imagine the following data:

```
fruit  code  quantity
apple  AD5      5
orange AB0      3
apple  AD5      4
```

I want to combine all codes to have unique codes, but without losing the link to "fruit".

It should become:

```
fruit  code  quantity
apple  AD5      9
orange AB0      3
```

For one code, I want to merge all its values in the "quantity" column, thereby removing all duplicate codes in the "code" column. All that while keeping the code linked to its respective fruit.

Comment: There is no 1 clear generic (free of names) statement of what you seek. So you cannot (re)search for previous Q&A--that can clearly be expected to exist. You show no research including re summing a column over rows with the same subrows. You use vague terms like "combine all" & "codes" & "link" & "merge" with unexplained idiosyncratic meanings instead of saying clearly how you want the result to be a function of the input. PS When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values.

Answer (score 0):

You can group by unique combinations of `code` and `fruit`, summing up their `quantity` like this:

```py
df = df.groupby(["fruit", "code"])["quantity"].sum().reset_index()
```

The output:

| fruit | code | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| apple | AD5 | 9 |
| orange | AB0 | 3 |